# CSS Button not rendering correctly on iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, render

I have a button created with css on a web application, when I test the button on chrome on android the button renders fine and stays on top of everything because of the z-index property:

[image: Android Button]

But when I test the same thing on chrome on IOS it doesnt renders the button the way its supposed to be and doesnt respect the z-index property:

[image]

I tried to add "-webkit-appearance: none;" to the css but it didnt worked heres the css and html:

```css
#PINPOINT {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
}

#BUTTON {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
  height: 70px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 70px;
  column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
  perspective-origin: 227.828px 35px;
  transform-origin: 227.828px 35px;
  border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
  font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 21px Roboto, sans-serif;
  outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

#TEXT {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.156863) 0px 2px 5px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 2px 10px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55.5px;
  left: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 55.5px;
  will-change: opacity, transform;
  z-index: 1;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 27.75px 27.75px;
  transform-origin: 27.75px 27.75px;
  background: rgb(239, 83, 80) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 56px Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 14px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="PINPOINT">
  <div id="BUTTON">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="TEXT"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or working demo for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use flexbox to make them align horizontally and vertically center. Here's the code.

```css
#PINPOINT {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin: 15px auto;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5000;
}

#BUTTON {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
 height: 70px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 70px;
 column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
 perspective-origin: 227.828px 35px;
 transform-origin: 227.828px 35px;
 border: 0px none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588);
 font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 21px Roboto, sans-serif;
 outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.870588) none 0px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
}

#TEXT {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.156863) 0px 2px 5px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.117647) 0px 2px 10px 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 55.5px;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 55.5px;
 will-change: opacity, transform;
 z-index: 1;
 transform-origin: 27.75px 27.75px;
 background: rgb(239, 83, 80) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
 border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
 font: normal normal normal normal 14px / 56px Roboto, sans-serif;
 margin: 0px 0px 14px;
 outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;

 /*Use flexbox property to fix this.*/
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="PINPOINT">
  <div id="BUTTON">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="TEXT"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the code. Flexbox is the best way to fix the issues.